Reverse arc above letter
Using stackrel we can obtain a reverse arc above X: $\stackrel{\smile}{X}$
The reverse arc is not so close to X, what can we do to make it closer? Is there something similar to \wideparen but that allows to have a reverse arc above X closer than stackrel, without defining a new command?

I think that such an accent doesn't exist. The closest I can think of are \check or \breve from amsmath, but they are not horizontally extendable. However, this might be a satisfactory answer (but requires you to define a new command).

Is it possible to rotate the wideparen symbol?
